# How to pull Content via a Wordpress RSS Feed

Tags: wordpress, rss

Im currently using a cffeed tag to pull content from a Wordpress RSS feed. When i output #content# I should be receiving numerous paragraphs worth of text. However, its only outputting a short blurp followed by a "read more link". How Do I display all the text I'm pulling from the RSS feed?

Below is my code for pulling the RSS feed and displaying content.

```
<cfset rssUrl = "https://chasbroucktest.wordpress.com/feed/">        
<cffeed action="read" source="#rssUrl#" query="entries" properties="info">
<cfdump var="#entries#">
<cfoutput query="entries">
      <p>#content#</p><br/>
</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that chasbroucktest.wordpress.com is not your own site?

If it is then first steps would be to check your feed settings in the wp-admin menu;

> Options -> Reading
>   Under "Syndication Feeds", be sure you've selected "Full Text."

If its not then perhaps you could use a service such as feedburner to drag the full article from the source.

Comment: It is my site. And I have the "Full Text" option activated